# A telephone line carries thousands of signals at the same time. What keeps them from mixing and distorting each other?

Tags: electricity

All the signals traveling down a copper wire are traveling along the same wire, why don't they mix and interfere with each other?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112753/discussion-on-question-by-farsideofourmoon-a-telephone-line-carries-thousands-of). Please edit necessary clarifications (such as what you mean by "all the signals") into the question instead of putting it into comments.

Answer (score 3):

At the lowest level of description, there is no "all the signals." There is only one signal—a time varying voltage—that *encodes* all of the many different higer-level signals (e.g., many different virtual voice circuits).

There have been different ways of doing that over the years. The earliest schemes were based on *[frequency division multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-division_multiplexing)*. You could try asking on the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site if you want more information about that.

The next improvement was to turn the audio signals into digital data streams, and combine them on the same wire with [*time division multiplexing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing). Same people might help you to go deeper with that question too.

After that, telephone networking technology began to merge with computer networking technology. (Some "telephone" services these days actually send your digitized voice over the internet.) Computer networking is way to broad and deep to discuss here.

Also, it's not physics, so I'm giving this answer to the community and voting to close the question.

Comment: Well, Shannon's limit is a physical one and does come into the picture (grin)

Answer (score 0):

What keeps them from mixing is a family of techniques referred to as [multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing). The principal techniques for copper wires are time-division multiplexing ("Happy days. Over", "Roger. Over and out" type conversations) and frequency-division multiplexing (such as the old [ADSL landline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_digital_subscriber_line) Internet connection).

Optical fibres and mobile telephony get much more exotic.

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell’s equations are *linear*. Suppose you have $N$ individual solutions of these equations, each consisting of the charges, currents, and fields carrying the information for one conversation on the wire. Then the linearity of the equations means that the simple arithmetic *sum* of these charges, currents, and fields is also a solution.

This is called *superposition*. The signals simply add together, without interfering with each other in any way that distorts them. Distortion can only occur is there is *nonlinearity*.

Suppose each signal is at a different “carrier” frequency, with the signal’s information represented by modulating the amplitude or the frequency of the carrier wave. After they get combined into a sum, you can separate them later with a simple frequency filter. This is not how modern telephony works, but it is a simple way to understand how a wire can carry multiple signals that can later be separated.

Rather than imagining signals in a wire, it is “cleaner” to imagine two beams of light that cross, such as from two flashlights. This is conceptually simpler because are just fields and no charges or currents, and because the beams start and end as separate beams. Because “superposition is not interaction”, the electromagnetic waves comprising the light pass right through each other without distortion, scattering, etc. Note: This assumes that we are ignoring quantum effects that are completely negligible at ordinary light intensities.

Comment: IMO, at the level of the OP's question, we should not even be talking about waves. (IMO, that's also why I don't think it's a physics question.) The "frequency division multiplexing" answer only needs the OP to understand that the instantaneous "value" of the combined signal is the sum of the instantaneous values of all of modulated "carriers" and, to understand that something called "band pass filter" can be used to select any one of them and reject all of the others. The fact that the "time varying signal" propagates down the wire as a wave is completely out of scope for what OP is asking.

Comment: @SolomonSlow If you don’t think it is a physics question, you should have voted to close it rather than answering it. I, on the other hand, think it is a physics question and answered it as such. I have no idea what the level of the OP is. They declined to answer this when I asked in now-deleted comments. My guess is that “multiplexing” is as new a concept as “linearity” and “superposition”. But I am fairly confident that the OP has some idea of what a wave is.

Comment: I _did_ vote to close, but I also want to help the OP, so I left an "answer" with a link that suggests a more appropriate place to ask the question, and with some ideas about how to better focus the question. I see that at least two somebodies have upvoted my answer, but don't worry! I won't get any points for that because I gave the answer to the "community." I imagine you can edit it yourself or maybe even delete it if you think it's not appropriate. Hopefully, the OP has read it by now anyway.

Comment: I have gotten reprimanded in the past for voting to close and then answering. I suggest not doing that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I almost never edit other people’s answers. I don’t have the power to unilaterally delete answers, nor would I want to even vote to delete yours, or downvote it. It is a perfectly reasonable answer, which I am not criticizing. You are criticizing mine. And that’s fine too. We can disagree on the right way to answer this vague question.